# Javascript 'type error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined' but works

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with the `backgroundColor` property in JavaScript but my function keeps working, regardless of the error.

Can somebody explain, how this is happening?
[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/wLtx753g/1/)

Thank you

JavaScript Code with error:

```
function surligne(champ, erreur)
{
 if(erreur)
 {
  champ.style.backgroundColor = "#fba";
  document.getElementById("messageErreur").style.display ="block";
 } 

 else
 {
  champ.style.backgroundColor = "";
  document.getElementById("messageErreur").style.display ="none";
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your error:

```
champ.addEventListener("blur", verifMail);
function verifMail(champ) {
```

change it to this:

```
champ.addEventListener("blur", verifMail);
function verifMail() {
```

Champ is already defined at the top of the file, by adding a parameter on the `verifyMail` function, you make it so that the function can no longer view the the champ variable at the top of the file and instead it sees the blur event.

The reason it does change color is because you call `verifMail` from the `verifForm` function, passing the `champ` parameter.

Comment: Perfect explanation !
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NicolasBROSSARD Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

The loss of focus triggers the blur. It is odd that the blur comes first.that's why on focus out your function again is calling so your error happened. I've correct it with variable value hope it'll help you

If you change the alerts to console.log (or something that does not steal focus), you will see that the events fire correctly.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('maPopin');

var btn = document.getElementById("monBouton");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("fermer")[0];

var champ = document.getElementById("mail");

var erreur = true;


btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
});

span.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
});

window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
});

champ.addEventListener("blur", verifMail);
champ.addEventListener("focus", verifMail);
function verifMail(champ)
{
   var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
   if(!regex.test(champ.value))
   {
      surligne(champ, true);
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      surligne(champ, false);
      return true;
   }
   
}

function surligne(champ, erreur)
{  if(champ.type !="focus" && champ.type !=="blur"){
   if(erreur)
   {
      champ.style.backgroundColor = "#fba";
      document.getElementById("messageErreur").style.display ="block";
   } 
    
   else
   {
      champ.style.backgroundColor = "";
      }
      }
      document.getElementById("messageErreur").style.display ="none";
   }
   
/* } */

champ.addEventListener("keyup", verifForm);

function verifForm()
{
   var mailOk = verifMail(champ);
   
   if(mailOk)
   {
   document.getElementById('submit1').disabled=0;
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
   document.getElementById('submit1').disabled=1; 
      return false;
      document.getElementById("messageErreur").style.display ="none";
   }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* Background pop-in */
.popin {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto; 
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

/* Style de la pop-in */
.popin-style {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #529D93;
  width: 35%;
}

/* Bouton fermer */
.fermer {
  color: #3f3f3f;
  float: right;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bob-style
{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.fermer:hover,
.fermer:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#messageErreur
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Exemple de Pop-in</h2>
  <button id="monBouton">Qui sommes nous ?</button>
  <div id="maPopin" class="popin">
   <div class="popin-style">
    <span class="fermer">&times;</span>
    <p>Cet objectif a été réalisé par Guillaume et Nicolas... Alias Bob et Patrick </p>
    <img src="http://www.chamalow-shop.com/images/t/tds/TDS-bob-patrick-geek-vert-g.gif" class="bob-style">
    <form>
     <label for="email">Veuillez saisir votre email :</label>
     <input  type="text" name="email" id="mail" placeholder="Email...">
     <button type="submit" id="submit1" disabled="disabled">Envoyer</button>
     <p id="messageErreur">Adresse email incorrecte</p>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

champ.style.backgroundColor = "";

the background color should be set to some value, how can it be blank ?